# Should a website always have a sticky footer

Tags: website-design, footers, lookandfeel

Trend goes that developers want to have a sticky footer in their site. If the content is well below the view port, the footer goes out of screen. Otherwise it is visible at the bottom of the screen.

If I do not make the footer sticky  then if the content height is less than that of the view port , the footer will be visible just below the content. And if the content is of much height then the footer will go down the view port.

Is a non-sticky footer a good design from UX perspective ?

Comment: No they should not always.

Answer (score 0):

A footer should be placed and fixed at the bottom of the document page, not right below the content.

Edit: let me clarify.
I think having the footer at the bottom adds a more finished look, adds closure to the design. There won't be any confusion as to where is the content area, and where it ends. Whereas having a lot of white space below the footer can feel as though there's something unfinished, that the footer is floating, that there might be content below that hasn't loaded yet.

Visually it adds a [*frame*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framing_(visual_arts)) to the whole page, which is something quite important (artists visually 'frame' their compositions in paintings and photographs in one way or another)

[image: Sticky footer vs footer below content]

Comment: why can't it be right below the content ? What is the justification if the footer has only one line of text ?

Comment: You'd end up with a lot of white space below the footer.

Comment: why is that any problem ?

Comment: I edited my comment and elaborated

Comment: Why not right below the content? Well because you could seriously stuff up other important factors such as legal requirements and Accessibility with an endlessly-scrolling content list. Like Nike did last year.